# IntelliJ + git failing to push: "Not setting branch master as its own upstream"

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, repository, push

I am a very Junior engineer.
I'm trying to push a new project to GitHub. I created a GitHub account and a repository named TeamBuilder.
When I try to push the project to GitHub via Git/IntelliJ, I get the following error:

[image]

So, when I try to do a pull/merge or a pull/branch default, I get this error:

[image]

I've read through a few SO posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493396/git-master-branch-has-no-upstream-branch) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700767/warning-not-setting-branch-master-as-its-own-upstream), but I'm not sure I understand the command lines, even after reading about them in the Git help documentation.

When I try to set the upstream branch to master, I get this error:

> Warning: Not setting branch master as its own upstream.

How can I successfully push this project to my GitHub repo? I'd like some help on this before I continue down the rabbit hole and break something.

Answer (score 1):

Update project action in IntelliJ wants the current branch to have a configured tracked remote counterpart and fails if there is no such.
So to make it work you can set a tracking from the command line with `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` command.

Note `origin/master`, not a simple `master` - this should be a reference to a remote branch. Using such reference is only possible when there is a remote defined in git-config. IntelliJ can help with setting remotes, check `VCS - Git - Remotes...`

As a side note, you can use the Share on GitHub action in IntelliJ to push new projects to GitHub - the action will automatically create a new repo and push the code.

Comment: "The requested upstream branch origin/master does not exist" when I try to use the git branch command. I will try the Share on GitHub action...

Comment: Do you have the origin remote set? Try calling `git fetch`